# Help in finding a particular connector

Tags: connector

I'm looking for help to find a specific connector to complement a PCI Express/PCI Connector. I show it in the red circle mark. The photos are from [this](https://pt.aliexpress.com/item/4000108480702.html?src=google&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI1amFytiT6gIVWojVCh3DNwGtEAQYAyABEgKifPD_BwE) HAT for a RaspPi. What is the name of this type of connector?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

That looks like an m3 or m2.5 broaching nut, but by the looks of it, it is not a solderable nut. It looks more like a press fit broaching nut, that is used for pressing into sheet metal or plastic. (you can tell by the corrugation on the sides which is typical of broaching nuts.)

A better way to do this is to use a solderable nut that is built for PCB's like these:

Some better options are listed here:

https://www.pemnet.com/fastening-products/fasteners-for-mounting-into-printed-circuit-boards-2/#

https://www.adafruit.com/product/4206

https://www.digikey.com/en/product-highlight/k/keystone/surface-mount-threaded-standoffs

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll look at the possibilities. I just realized it needs to be quite high. At least 7.38mm [because of the PCI card](https://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=srchrtrv&DocNm=1759546&DocType=Customer+Drawing&DocLang=English&PartCntxt=1759546-1&DocFormat=pdf)

Comment: PEM nuts are usually the best, if you want your PCB assembled they also come in tape and work with SMT assembling equipment and also work with solder and ovens. They also come in lots of different heights. If you can't find your height then get one a little shorter and make up the difference with washers.